# Bootstrap grid nesting columns issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I am trying to do is to have two columns of 3 nested pink squares each, at the large and med settings, then on small screen tablet a single column with 3 pink squares then another single column with 3 pink squares under that. Then at the xs mobile level I'm trying to again have two columns but with 1 column of nested pink squares in each. I thought this is what my css is requesting, but that's not what is happening :(  What am I doing wrong here?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/asNocx5qQmAOqiNTEZXG?p=preview)

Here's the html:

```
 <div class="container">   
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><h4>My Subtitle</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="x in things"> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="cube">
            <b>{{x.title}}</b> </br> {{x.content}}

          </div>                
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><h4>My Subtitle 2</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="x in things2"> 
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="cube">
            <b>{{x.title}}</b> </br> {{x.content}}

          </div>                
         </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You have sx, should be xs

Comment: I just posted a fix to your angular and now it is your html boilerplate. Source of the problem is simple. You are rushing things. Take your time to absorb dude...

Comment: @ODelibalta  :) Actually, I was trying to post the above, but ran into an angular problem :D Thanks for helping on the other one :)

Comment: @ScottSimpson Thanks Scott, now the pink boxes are reverting back to two columns each on xs, instead what I want which is two single columns (two outer columns with a single nested column of pink squares each). Also, why are they stacking horizontally on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

halfzebra is right. If you you nest columns you always have new 12 columns inside another one.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            This will fill col-md-6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And like in example above I always like to use rows when Im starting one.

I don't know if I got you right but you could do something like this:

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4>My Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in things">
                    <div class="cube">
                        <b>{{x.title}}</b> </br> {{x.content}}
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4>My Subtitle 2</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in things2">
                    <div class="cube">
                        <b>{{x.title}}</b> </br> {{x.content}}  
                    </div>              
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that your red boxes are not always fitting in to the columns. I changed width to 100% so you can see how columns are acting.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EE4eWrrGIJ0lFdPBcq7T?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much, yes this is what I ended up figuring out too, thanks for the clarification and explanation. I think bootstrap can be a bit of a headtrip to begin with :D  - I'm wondering tho, whether 150px width is the best width for these cubes (these are actually representative of thumbnail images that tile), with respect to 320px for mobile and whatever for tablet, as what I have with the 15px gutter makes 360 on mobile I guess.   I notice playing around with my fixed width cubes the gutters disappear at times, I wonder why. Anyhow, thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're confused by the number at the end of the class.

While nesting `.col-xs-6` inside another `.col-xs-6`, you will get a column which takes only 50% of the width.

It's a primary principle of 12 column grid. Divide `100% / 12 = 8.33333333333%` and you will get `width` property of a single column in **percents**, please have in mind that the width in percents is calculated according to the parent width.

Bootstrap's grid is not informative while nesting.

Eg. think of `.col-xs-6` as `width: 50%;`, `.col-xs-4` is `width: 33.33333%;`

Comment: Agentzebra reporting to @halfzebra . So you mean that .col-xs-6 inside .col-xs-6 is actually 25%, that's a good clarification, I thought that's the way it was, tho being dyslexic it's easy to misunderstand that 6 means 1/2 and not 6 and actually write the wrong col number. Haha. I think I also need to understand better the optimal pixel sizes for the columns. Thanks for your help and explanation. From one Zebra to another, it's much appreciated :D